# Using pyramid_mailer results in ValueError: TPC in progress

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm running pyramid on an Ubuntu Linux server, and am getting a `ValueError` when trying to use `pyramid_mailer`. My code is relatively simple, anything seems to cause it:

```
def my_view(request):
     mailer = get_mailer(request)
     emailMessage = Message(subject="Welcome", sender="noreply@mysite.com", recipients = ["me@email.com"], body="test")
     mailer.send(emailMessage)
```

Results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 242, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 217, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 160, in toolbar_tween
    return handler(request)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 79, in tm_tween
    manager.abort()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_manager.py", line 116, in abort
    return self.get().abort()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 468, in abort
    reraise(t, v, tb)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 453, in abort
    rm.abort(self)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/wwwProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/repoze.sendmail-4.2-py2.7.egg/repoze/sendmail/delivery.py", line 119, in abort
    raise ValueError("TPC in progress")
ValueError: TPC in progress
```

I followed the instructions for "Getting Started (The Easier Way)" on this site: http://pyramid-mailer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.sendmail/issues/31).  It can be worked around in the meantime by reverting to repoze.sendmail 4.1 (from 4.2)

Answer (score 1):

```
recipients = ["me@email.com"]
```

[here](http://pyramid-mailer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#pyramid_mailer.message.Message) you can see

- recipients – list of email addresses

Answer (score 0):

This was the first error that I encountered while trying to set up an emailing system, through I cannot remember what I did.  In any case, I finally got it working for a gmail sender for SMTP.  Hope this someone else in my position:

```
import smtplib

sender = "noreply"
to = "username"
subject = "Verification Code"

headers = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n" % (sender, to,
subject)

sEmailMessage = headers + "whatever message you want"

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
#--- because of gmail
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.ehlo()
#---
mailserver.login("your_email_address@gmail.com", "your_password")

mailserver.sendmail("from_here@gmail.com", to_here@whatever.com, sEmailMessage)
mailserver.close()
```